# Swift SpriteKit problem with SKNodes in a grid configuration

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a “simple” game where the user will “pop” blocks by tapping on “clusters” of blocks.  When the user taps it destroys the “cluster” of blocks, the other blocks move down to fill in the empty spots on the board, and new ones come in from the top to fill the board back up.  The first time the user taps, everything works perfectly.  All blocks move down to fill in the missing spots and new ones come on screen:
[image]

After the user taps the second time, everything seems to get out of place:
[image]

The container that the blocks are created in and added as children is an SKShapeNode, and in the screenshot it is the area inside the “gray” line.  The white boxes to the left, right and bottom are my attempt to keep the blocks inside the “level” node from moving out of place.  It obviously doesn’t help.

Here is my code for creating the initial set of “blocks” and adding them to “level”:

```
func addBlocks() {
    var row = 0
    var col = 0
    var id = 0
    for r in stride(from: 13, through: frame.width, by: blockSize.width) {
        for c in stride(from: 13, through: frame.height - blockSize.height * 4, by: blockSize.height) {
            let color = level!.generateColors.chooseSet(colorSet: level!.generateColors)
            let position = CGPoint(x: r, y: c)
            let block = BlockEntity(name: "Box-\(id)", 
                                    color: color, 
                                    blockSize: blockSize,
                                    position: position, 
                                    pointValue: 60, 
                                    column: col, 
                                    row: row)
            addChild(block)
            blocks.append(BlockData(id: id, 
                                    position: block.position, 
                                    block: block, 
                                    row: row, 
                                    col: col)
            )
            id += 1
            col += 1
        }    
        row += 1
    }
}
```

The code to fill in the empty spots when the blocks are popped is:

```
func fillInBlocks() {
    repeat {
        let missingBlocks = blocks.filter({ $0.block == nil })
        for missing in missingBlocks {
            let col = missing.col
            let column = blocks.filter({ $0.col == col })
            for missing in column {
                if missing.block == nil {
                    repeat {                         
                        if let blockExistsIndex = blocks.firstIndex(where: { $0.col == missing.col + 1 && $0.row == missing.row && $0.block != nil }) {
                            if let missingBlockIndex = blocks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == missing.id }) {
                                guard let existingBlock = blocks[blockExistsIndex].block else { return }
                                let move = SKAction.move(to: blocks[missingBlockIndex].position, duration: 0.25)
                                existingBlock.run(move) 
                                blocks[missingBlockIndex].block = blocks[blockExistsIndex].block
                                blocks[blockExistsIndex].block = nil
                            }
                        }
                    } while blocks.first(where: { $0.col == missing.col + 1 && $0.row == missing.row })?.block != nil
                    
                    if missing.position.y.rounded() == 438.0 {
                        if let index = blocks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == missing.id }) {
                            let color = level!.generateColors.chooseSet(colorSet: level!.generateColors)

                            var position = CGPoint(x: blocks[index].position.x, y: 475)
                            let block = BlockEntity(
                                name: "Box-\(blocks[index].id)", 
                                color: color, 
                                blockSize: blockSize,
                                position: position, 
                                pointValue: 60, 
                                column: blocks[index].col, 
                                row: blocks[index].row
                            )
                            
                            blocks[index].block = block
                            position = CGPoint(x: blocks[index].position.x, y: 440)
                            let move = SKAction.move(to: position, duration: 0.25)
                            blocks[index].block?.run(move)
                            addChild(block)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while blocks.filter({ $0.block == nil }).count > 0
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this so that it will reliably move the blocks without causing the “wreck” seen when the user taps the second time?

Also it should be noted that I used this article by Kodeco as inspiration to getting my blocks to align in a grid and get filled in when blocks are removed:
[How to make a game like candy crush](https://www.kodeco.com/55-how-to-make-a-game-like-candy-crush-with-spritekit-and-swift-part-1)

Also note, I am not making a game like Candy Crush LOL.

Comment: looks like you are relying on the physics engine? yes that will produce micro movements with lots of variation as the blocks all jostle against each other. for a game like this i would skip the physics engine and code the downward block movement yourself, that way it will be precise and locked in. (another thing to try: go into the physics engine for the blocks and disable/override x-axis movement, which might solve your problems.)

Comment: I actually solved this by doing just as you mentioned.  I coded the block movements myself.